# XSLT check - If Parent node has child node, make xml equivalent as Y

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml like:

```
<EnhancedData>
                  <EmailAddress>abc.def@email.com</EmailAddress>
                  <PassengerName>ABC/DEF</PassengerName>
                  <RecordLocator_PNR>ABCDEF</RecordLocator_PNR>
</EnhancedData>
```

Corresponding XSLT that I am using looks like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="EnhancedData">
            <xsl:if test="*">
              <EnhancedData>
                <xsl:value-of select="Y" />
              </EnhancedData>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:for-each select="EnhancedData/EmailAddress">
          <EmailAddress>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </EmailAddress>
          </xsl:for-each>
           <xsl:for-each select="EnhancedData/PassengerName">
          <PassengerName>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </PassengerName>
          </xsl:for-each>
           <xsl:for-each select="EnhancedData/RecordLocator_PNR">
          <RecordLocator_PNR>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </RecordLocator_PNR>
          </xsl:for-each>
```

I am using a Java code which transforms the xml into another o/p file using the XSLT. I need to make Enhanced Data as Y, if it contains any child node.

With the current code, the output xml looks like:

```
<EnhancedData/>
<EmailAddress>abc.def@email.com</EmailAddress>
<PassengerName>ABC/DEF</PassengerName>
<RecordLocator_PNR>ABCDEF</RecordLocator_PNR>
```

What I need is :

```
<EnhancedData>Y</EnhancedData>
<EmailAddress>abc.def@email.com</EmailAddress>
<PassengerName>ABC/DEF</PassengerName>
<RecordLocator_PNR>ABCDEF</RecordLocator_PNR>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="Y" />
```

just use

```
<xsl:text>Y</xsl:text>
```

Comment: The following code works: <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="EnhancedData/PassengerName != ''">
              <EnhancedData>Y</EnhancedData>
            </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
   <EnhancedData>N</EnhancedData>
   </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>